# How to sum up values in a php column

Tags: php, sql

Im trying to sum up all the values in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEAXT.png) data base but for some reason i cant do i, I looked all over stack overflow and tried multiple methods but none seem to work. My current code is

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
//INCLUDES//
include 'config.php';
//INCLUDES//

//DATA FETCH//
$rank=$_POST['R'];
$drank=$_POST['DR'];
//DATA FETCH//


//MYSQL STUFF//
$con=mysqli_connect($ip,$login,$password,$dbname);

for ($i = $rank; $i <= $drank; $i++) { // LOOP UNTIL 20 IS MET

$s=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT sum(rankprice) FROM cost WHERE rank='$i'");
if($s === FALSE) { //CHECK IF DATA IS THERE
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con)); // IF NOT THERE SEND ERROR
}
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($s); //PUT DATA IN ROW
echo $row[0];


}
?>
```

It connects to the database no problem. When I use `echo $row[0];` it prints all the values of the column in order. Ive tried putting it into an array and printing it but it seems that doesnt work either. The only way it seems to work is when I add ALL the values in the column by removing `WHERE rank='$i'` in the SQL code which I dont want to do. Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query :

```
$rankarr = array();
for ($i = $rank; $i <= $drank; $i++) { // LOOP UNTIL 20 IS MET
    $rankarr[] = $i;
}

$rankarr = implode(',', $rankarr);


$s=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT sum(rankprice) As myrank FROM cost WHERE rank in ($rankarr)");
if($s === FALSE) { //CHECK IF DATA IS THERE
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con)); // IF NOT THERE SEND ERROR
}
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($s); //PUT DATA IN ROW
```

Comment: Tried it, i reassigned the echo to fit the AS , but it still prints everything in order like this : 1313141416202025253040

Comment: Can you explain what kind of logic you want? From your code it appears that you are querying for a particular rank which is unique in table and hence the sum will always return the same value. e.g. for rank -> 1, only one entry is there in table and thus sum(rankprice) with where clause (rank=1) will return only 9.

Comment: I want to add up all rows in that columns that fit the 'rank='$i'', ive gotten all the numbers that i want i just dont know how to add them up =/

Comment: Use this query: **mysqli_query($con, "SELECT sum(rankprice) As myrank FROM cost WHERE rank in ($rankarr))** where $rankarr is an array with comma separated values of ranks e.g. 1,2,3

Comment: Any chance you could implement that into the whole code because im getting some errors and i've no idea how to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

You now want to get the sum value of rankprice in one same rank. So the result of sum() will differ from the rank in one sql. You should tell mysql by adding group by clause, which group the table by rank and get the sum() of each group.

```
 $s=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT sum(rankprice) FROM cost WHERE rank='$i' GROUP BY rank ");
```

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE rank='5'' at line 1 , error from that sql code.

Comment: sorry, just append group by at last. I made a mistake. You may try the sql first in you phpMyadmin.

Comment: Jack, your answer is pretty short. You may want to add some explanations.